# Ubuntu 20.04: keyboard and mousepad not working after installation

Tags: updates, keyboard, xorg, 20.04

I've been following a lot of issues here that relates to this one - so it might be a possible duplicate, however since I didn't see it for 20.04 version, I think it's a new one.
The issue is:

1. I have installed (via USB that contained a downloaded version from Official website) the Ubuntu 20.04 new OS. - **Please note this is a fresh installation**.
2. After rebooting, the keyboard and mousepad are just not working.
3. They are working if I am getting to tty (for example) / BIOS, however not in the login page / in the OS.

I have followed each and any guide here about installing / updating `xserver-xorg-input-all` again and again, however this isn't seems to solve the issue.

Hardware:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
    product: Inspiron 7348 (0675)
       product: 067RT2
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
             product: HMT41GS6BFR8A-PB
          product: Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI
             product: HD Graphics 5500
             product: Broadwell-U Audio Controller
             product: Broadwell-U Processor Thermal Subsystem
             product: Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                   product: USB Receiver
                   product: ST_SENSOR_HUB
                   product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
                   product: Touchscreen
                product: xHCI Host Controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1
             product: Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3
                product: Wireless 7265
             product: Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller
                product: EHCI Host Controller
            product: Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
                product: LITEONIT LCS-256
             product: Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          product: PnP device PNP0303
          product: PnP device DLL065a
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
       product: DELL 0WF28498
       product: OEM Define 5
```

My questions:

1. Did anyone else suffer from this problem? Where you reboot - install the xserver using an external (for example) keyboard and mouse - then it works. Then after another reboot - it does not work? Specifically after upgrading to 20.04!
2. How can I solve it? Please assist as it is a critical issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Ubuntu thinks your PC is a tablet and diables the keyboard.
The fix below works if the following command gives you any number that is **not** `31` or `32`.

```bsh
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type
```

**How to fix this:** (from https://askubuntu.com/a/1282269/558457)

> There is a bug in recent kernels that disables some laptop keyboards. Mainly Acer and HP so far.  Can usually go to recovery and boot from kernel 5.4.0-42 or use an external keyboard.
>
> Blacklisting the `intel_vbtn` kernel module is a workaround for this, as seen in [Why my laptop's keyboard screwed up since kernel 5.4.0-47 till 5.8.0-20](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/)
>
> To implement this, you can either create a new file in `/etc/modprobe.d` with the suffix `.conf` or use the main `blacklist.conf` file. The former may be preferable, since you can then just delete the file when it is no longer required (i.e. when the bug is fixed):
>
> `sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf`
>
> Add a line to the file, optionally with a comment explaining why you are doing this
>
> ```bsh
> # bug in module breaks keyboard, so don't load it
> blacklist intel_vbtn
> ```
>
> Save the file, exit and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Check drivers for your computer on your official computer brand driver page; normally you can select your operating system, and you will find the most common drivers for install, for mousepad for sure.

For example, in case of my hp:
https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-840-g1-notebook-pc/5405360

Comment: Hey, do you know how can I get drivers for ubuntu (e.g. .deb) and not .exe? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is in spanish. Please do only use english links.

Comment: I upload with english one, but anyway, It was an example, I dont think Daniel has exactly the same computer than me :)....For the drivers Daniel, you have to look for your own drivers. If you have a laptop, go to the official vendor web, and for should they provide the proper basic drivers for unix distributions.

Comment: David, thank you for this, but it might be irrelevant for me, as indeed this 20.04 has a bug in the keyboard. See comment above.